# PhpStorm it can not resolve root methods, for vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, phpstorm

- I am using PhpStorm from some days, for **laravel** projects.
- I have attached a my **Index.vue** file as screenshot.
- I have define a **mf** method in my **app.js**
- I want to go where **$root.mf** method is
  defined, but there are issue with PhpStorm it can not resolve that
  function.
- **It is possible for PhpStorm can auto detect $root (app.js)
  functions inside in any child component??**

How to resolve
[image]

Answer (score 2):

the issue is tracked at [WEB-52054](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-52054), please follow it for updates